# How to submit a form in HTML without checking any of the radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have designed a google web app wherein I am using HTML and JS. I have a form with multiple radio buttons corresponding to several questions. I want the form to get submitted, even if no radio buttons corresponding to any question is selected.
At present, the form is not getting submitted, if i dont check all the radio buttons(i mean the one corresponding to each question). I have not done any validation here.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var selectBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('select');
  M.FormSelect.init(selectBoxes);

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateDates).getCalendarBusyDays();

});

function populateDates(disableDays) {

  var datePicker = document.getElementById('prefDate');
  M.Datepicker.init(datePicker, {
    disableDayFn: function(day) {
      return disableDays.indexOf(day.valueOf()) > -1;
    }
  });

}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", buttonClickAction);
document.getElementById("ctn").addEventListener("click", buttonAuto);
document.getElementById("tc").addEventListener("input", getTestname);

function buttonAuto() {

  setTimeout(buttonClickAction, 600000);

}


function buttonClickAction() {

  var toValidate = {
    fn: "First Name Required",
    ln: "Last Name Required",
    exm: "Registered Exam required",
    prefDate: "Date of slot required",
    tc: "Test Code required"

  };

  var idkeys = Object.keys(toValidate);

  var allValid = true;
  idkeys.forEach(function(id) {
    var isValid = checkIfValid(id, toValidate[id]);

    if (!isValid) {
      allValid = false;
    }

  });

  if (allValid) {

    addRecord();

  }

} //closing

function checkIfValid(elID, message) {

  var isValid = document.getElementById(elID).checkValidity();

  if (!isValid) {
    //warn the user
    M.toast({
      html: message
    });
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

//closed

function addRecord() {

  var userInfo = {};

  userInfo.firstName = document.getElementById("fn").value;
  userInfo.lastName = document.getElementById("ln").value;
  userInfo.exm = document.getElementById("exm").value;
  userInfo.tn = document.getElementById("tn").value;
  userInfo.date = document.getElementById("prefDate").value;
  userInfo.a1 = document.querySelector('input[name="q1"]:checked').value;
  userInfo.a2 = document.querySelector('input[name="q2"]:checked').value;
  userInfo.a3 = document.querySelector('input[name="q3"]:checked').value;
  userInfo.a4 = document.querySelector('input[name="q4"]:checked').value;
  userInfo.a5 = document.querySelector('input[name="q5"]:checked').value;
  userInfo.a6 = document.querySelector('input[name="q6"]:checked').value;
  userInfo.a7 = document.querySelector('input[name="q7"]:checked').value;
  userInfo.a8 = document.querySelector('input[name="q8"]:checked').value;
  userInfo.a9 = document.querySelector('input[name="q9"]:checked').value;
  userInfo.a10 = document.querySelector('input[name="q10"]:checked').value;

  google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);
  document.getElementById("fn").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ln").value = "";
  document.getElementById("tc").value = "";
  document.getElementById("tn").value = "";
  document.getElementById("prefDate").value = "";
  document.getElementById("questions").reset();
  M.updateTextFields();

  var myApp = document.getElementById("exm");
  myApp.selectedIndex = 0;
  M.FormSelect.init(myApp);


}

function getTestname() {

  var testCode = document.getElementById("tc").value;

  if (testCode.length === 3) {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updatename).getTest(testCode);

  }
}

function updatename(name) {
  document.getElementById("tn").value = name;
  M.updateTextFields();
}

const startingMinutes = 10;
let time = startingMinutes * 60;

const countdownEl = document.getElementById('countdown');

setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);

function updateCountdown() {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;

  seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

  countdownEl.innerHTML = `${minutes}: ${seconds}`;
  time !== 0 ? time-- : time;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <?!=include("page-css");?>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #e0f2f1;">

  <h3>LIVE TEST 1.0</h3>

  <div class="container">

    <p2>Time Remaining : </p2>
    <p3 id="countdown">10:00</p3>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input id="fn" type="text" class="validate" required>
        <label for="fn">First Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input id="ln" type="text" class="validate" required>
        <label for="ln">Last Name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--CLOSE ROW-->

    <div class="row">

      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <select id="exm" required>
          <option disabled selected>Exam registered</option>

          <?!= list; ?>

        </select>
        <label>Exam prefered</label>
      </div>

      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input id="prefDate" type="text" class="datepicker" required>
        <label for="prefDate">Slot Date</label>
      </div>


    </div>
    <!--CLOSE ROW-->

    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input id="tc" type="text" class="validate" required pattern="^\d{3}$">
        <label for="tc">Test Code</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input disabled id="tn" type="text" class="validate">
        <label for="tn" class=active>Test Name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--CLOSE ROW-->


    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">

        <a button id="ctn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small blue accent-3"><i class="material-icons left">play_arrow</i>Start Test</a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!--CLOSE ROW-->


    <h4>Quantative Section</h4>

    <div class="row">
      <form id="questions">
        <p>What is the sum of 20 and 5?</p>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="30"><span>30</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="25"><span>25</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="15"><span>15</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="35"><span>35</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="hidden" name="q1" value="null"><span></span></label>


        <p>What is the quotient of 125 and 5?</p>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="30"><span>30</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="25"><span>25</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="15"><span>15</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="35"><span>35</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="hidden" name="q2" value="null"><span></span></label>

        <p>What is the square root 225?</p>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="30"><span>30</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="25"><span>25</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="15"><span>15</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="35"><span>35</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="hidden" name="q3" value="null"><span></span></label>

        <p>What is the difference of 25 and 5?</p>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q4" value="30"><span>30</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q4" value="25"><span>25</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q4" value="20"><span>20</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q4" value="35"><span>35</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="hidden" name="q4" value="null"><span></span></label>

        <p>What is the product of 25 and 5?</p>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q5" value="30"><span>30</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q5" value="125"><span>125</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q5" value="15"><span>15</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q5" value="35"><span>35</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="hidden" name="q5" value="null"><span></span></label>

        <h5>Verbal Section</h5>

        <p>Who created Auracle?</p>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q6" value="Willian brother"><span>Willian brother</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q6" value="Co-brothers"><span>Co-brothers</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q6" value="Thorappans"><span>Thorappans</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q6" value="Njangal thanne"><span>Njangal thanne</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="hidden" name="q6" value="null"><span></span></label>

        <p>What wrote Wings of fire?</p>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q7" value="J.K.Nair"><span>J.K.Nair</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q7" value="Sonastin"><span>Sonastin</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q7" value="A.P.J Abdul Kalam"><span>A.P.J Abdul Kalam</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q7" value="None of these"><span>None of these</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="hidden" name="q7" value="null"><span></span></label>

        <p>Which below is a figure of speech?</p>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q8" value="Similie"><span>Similie</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q8" value="Smile"><span>Smile</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q8" value="Simili"><span>Simili</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q8" value="Methapor"><span>Methapor</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="hidden" name="q8" value="null"><span></span></label>

        <p>Who is the author of daffodils?</p>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q9" value="Rutherford"><span>Rutherford</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q9" value="Shakesphere"><span>Shakesphere</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q9" value="Rowling"><span>Rowling</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q9" value="R.K.Menon"><span>R.K.Menon</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="hidden" name="q9" value="null"><span></span></label>

        <p>What is the meaning of develop?</p>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q10" value="Create"><span>Create</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q10" value="Made"><span>Made</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q10" value="Destruct"><span>Destruct</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q10" value="None of these"><span>None of these</span></label><br>
        <label><input type="hidden" name="q10" value="null"><span></span></label>

      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">

        <a button id="btn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small blue accent-3"><i class="material-icons left">play_arrow</i>Submit Test</a>

        <a href="<?=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?>?v=result" button id="btn1" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small blue accent-3"><i class="material-icons left">account_balance_wallet</i>Result</a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!--CLOSE ROW-->

  </div>
  <!--CLOSE CONTAINER-->

  <div id="result"></div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <?!=include("page-js");?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: remove "required" from them

Comment: required is for the text boxes not for the radio buttons. I need validation on those text fields, but no validation on radio button

Comment: If some body can help me in this immediately then it will be of great help. I request you to please connect with me, contact : +91 9895455730

Comment: That’s not how SO works

Comment: I didn't got what you meant. Can I share the file with you on email?

Comment: We are not going to call you. It’s not rent a coder

Comment: So if there are no required on the radio, what happens when you submit? Your snippet does not work due to the missing `google` script

Comment: There is no required in the radio. But when i click submit, the data is not passed on, I mean form does not respond.I have multiple files actually. Is it possible to share via some email

Comment: Sorry to bother, because I am new here

Comment: I never used google script. I have no idea what is missing. Right now I cannot even debug because the JS does not load in the developer tools